Incorrect values for text bbox patch in matplotlib
I have added text with a border box in matpotlib using ax.annotate. I want to know what height and width of this box is. I tried retrieving this using the get_bbox_patch() function, which should return the XY coordinates of the lower left corner of the box, and also the width and the height of the rectangle according to the documentation
However as you can see below, the two texts objects are clearly at different locations and have differing widths but return the same incorrect values. Does anybody know what the issue could be?
Input
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))
ax.scatter([1,3,5,7,3], [3,6,7,4,2])
text_obj = ax.annotate('foo', (2,3), color='red', ha='center', va='center', fontsize= 12, bbox=dict(facecolor='#FFFFFF', boxstyle='round4,pad=0'))
text_obj2 = ax.annotate('barbarbar', (4,5), color='blue', ha='center', va='center', fontsize= 12, bbox=dict(facecolor='#FFFFFF', boxstyle='round4,pad=0'))

print(text_obj.get_bbox_patch())
print(text_obj2.get_bbox_patch()

Resulting plot
Output:
FancyBboxPatch((0, 0), width=1, height=1)
FancyBboxPatch((0, 0), width=1, height=1)


Does this answer your question?
